# Adding more data to the "commerce/cart/update-cart" action

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce

Is it possible to add additional data to the "commerce/cart/update-cart" callback? For instance, we want to include an Asset field so we can populate a cart modal with the item's image in one call?

Or is there a better way to tackle this type of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could either [extend](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25907/overriding-basefrontendcontroller-in-craft-commerce) the craft commerce `update-cart controller`
or get the specific fields via `element-api` what will unfortunately result in an extra api call.